# if statement is not giving desired result in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have sales rep column, and their total sales. i am showing the results in the below matrix

[image]

so the actual value that i am trying to show from the calculated column as below.

```
FinalActual = if('Sales Target'[SalesRep] = "ABC",'Sales Target'[totalABC],'Sales Target'[totalseats]-'Sales Target'[totalseatspq] )
```

so I am trying to show the actual value based on the sales rep name. if the sales rep name is "ABC", then it should show the value of the measure which I created separately. for others it should be Sales Target'[totalseats]-'Sales Target'[totalseatspq]. But the issue here is, for ABC it's not taking the value from the "true condition(Sales Target'[totalABC])" of if statement. its still picking the value of the false condition(Sales Target'[totalseats]-'Sales Target'[totalseatspq]). Please help if I am missing anything here.

Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Please correct the image attachment.

Comment: corrected the image